# c# MVVM presentation logic

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new the the MVVM pattern.

The view has a login button and a progress bar.

I have a view model called LoginViewModel which exposes the command LoginCommand and is hooked up to my view LoginPage.xaml.

When the login command is executed the Login button should be disabled and the progress bar should become visible.

If login fails the the Login button should become enabled and the progress bar should be hidden.

What I am unsure about is where this presentation logic should happen.  Should it happen in the view mode or in the code behind of the page?

Currently I have a boolean property on the view model called LoggingIn which is set to true when the login process begins and then false if it fails.  This boolean is the hooked to the IsEnabled and Visibility property of the button and progress bar, respectively.

This felts wrong to me so I tried making a couple of events, OnBeginLogin and OnEndLogin and hooking these up in the code behind of the page which code to control the visual state of the controls.  This however required much more code than the previous solution.

I also though that I could expose two properties in the view model which are specific to the controls, LoginButtonEnabled and ProgressBarVisible so that I can control the visual state from the view model. But if I add a cancel button let say, then I would need to add another property called CancelButtonEnabled.

I think that the presentation logic should not be handled in the view model so adding an event seems to be the best solution but I'm wondering what is the best practice or standard/common way of doing it?

Also when login is successful, should returning the user to the previous page or another page be handled in the view model or in the code behind of the page? again I feel that this isn't something for the view model but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right about adding new property of state another button. That's why this called ViewModel.

Comment: Have you tried handling your presentation logic in xaml using DataTriggers? If you have complex presentation logic, you can use valueconverters to handle the logic and return a value that a DataTrigger can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it feels wrong to you, but your first approach seems the most correct to me. The view model is correctly exposing the application's state to the view, and then you're using data binding to control how this translates to presentation.

Comment: I think it feels wrong because to communicate a state change you would normally use an property of an enum type or an event.  For my simple situation a boolean will do but if you have a page for viewing, editing and inserting would you have three enum values "Viewing", "Editing" and "Inserting" rather than IsEditing, IsInserting but you can't use enum types in xaml easily so I thought that there must be a standard way of handling view state changes.

Comment: How about after login has succeeded, should the view model navigate to another page or should this be done in the code behind of the page?

Comment: I would navigate to another usercontrol. The way you hook up your application could be different. I normally only have a single MainWindow (ok I also have a PopupWindow but that's irrelevant). I put a usercontrol on my MainWindow, which is hooked up to a viewmodel property on my MainViewModel. When I want to "change" screens, I change the viewmodel property on my MainViewModel. DataTemplates on my MainWindow(or dictionary) detect that viewmodel has changed and load a different usercontrol => screen changes

Comment: The viewModel has to be the testable representation of your UI. So your first approach, or two properties in the view model which are specific to the controls are the most correct way to do ot in MVVM.